# Regex for ISBN and atrack Number

Tags: c#, regex

I have the below strings as possible file names from different supplier.

**9780307967121_UA_01_001_r1_128kbps.mp3**

**9780307967121_001.mp3**

**001_9780307967121.mp3**

**XX_9780307967121.mp3**

**WHERE :**

9780307967121 is **ISBN**
001 is **TrackNumber**

At the moment I am using split function to extract the ISBN and TrackNumber. TrackNumber can be NULL sometimes (the last example) . What i am planning to do is to define regular expression per supplier in the database and process the file name according to the regular expression for a chose supplier.

How would I write a regular expressions which returns the ISBN and TrackNumber and also must return null when ISBN or TrackNumber is not available in the filename?

I have actually tried to construct the regex as below

```
(\d{13})\w(\d{3})
```

but only captures one pattern.

### C# Code

```
           string pattern = @"(?:(?<ISBN>\d{10,13})|(?<TrackNumber>\d{3}))[^a-zA-Z]";

            string input = "9780307967121_UA_01_001_r1_128kbps.mp3";

            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                    Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(\d{10,13}).*?_(\d{3})|(\d{3}).*?_(\d{10,13})|(\d{10,13})(?=[^\d])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX0kU9/1)

Input

```
9780307967121_UA_01_001_r1_128kbps.mp3

9780307967121_001.mp3

001_9780307967121.mp3

XX_9780307967121.mp3
```

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-13]  `9780307967121`
2.  [20-23] `001`
MATCH 2
1.  [40-53] `9780307967121`
2.  [54-57] `001`
MATCH 3
3.  [63-66] `001`
4.  [67-80] `9780307967121`
MATCH 4
5.  [89-102]    `9780307967121`
```

Or

```
(?:(?<ISBN>\d{10,13})|(?<TrackNumber>\d{3}))[^a-zA-Z]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY0yS1/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
ISBN    [0-13]  `9780307967121`
MATCH 2
TrackNumber [20-23] `001`
MATCH 3
ISBN    [40-53] `9780307967121`
MATCH 4
TrackNumber [54-57] `001`
MATCH 5
TrackNumber [63-66] `001`
MATCH 6
ISBN    [67-80] `9780307967121`
MATCH 7
ISBN    [89-102]    `9780307967121`
```

Explanation:

`\d{10,13}` match a digit [0-9]. Quantifier: {10,13} Between 10 and 13 times.
`[^a-zA-Z]` match a single character not present in a-z or A-A

Comment: this one "(?:(?<ISBN>\d{10,13})|(?<TrackNumber>\d{3}))[^a-zA-Z]" includes the "-" too

Comment: @alan-b Why can it includes the "-" ?

Comment: the online demo works fine however C# code includes the "-"

Comment: `(?:(?<ISBN>\d{10,13})|(?<TrackNumber>\d{3}))(?![a-zA-Z])` this one can work

Answer (score 1):

This is nice and concise

```
(?|([0-9]{13})|([0-9]{3}))[^k]
```

[Regex101:](https://regex101.com/r/oI1eS7/1)

Arguments:

```
9780307967121_UA_01_001_r1_128kbps.mp3

9780307967121_001.mp3

001_9780307967121.mp3

XX_9780307967121.mp3
```

Returns:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-13]   `9780307967121`
2.  [20-23]  `001`
MATCH 2
1.  [40-53]  `9780307967121`
2.  [54-57]  `001`
MATCH 3
1.  [63-66]  `001`
2.  [67-80]  `9780307967121`
MATCH 4
1.  [89-102] `9780307967121`
```

Comment: @Icycicle , in C# it throws exception "Unrecognized grouping construct"